# Typescript NestJS LF cleaner way

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, nestjs, typeorm

Im currently working on a nestjs project and while coding i started wondering if there would be a much simpler way of writing the following code:

```js
async editCompany(editCompanyDto: EditCompanyDto, id: number) {
        const { companyName, telNr, fax, mail, website, notes } =
            editCompanyDto;

        const company = await this.findOne({ id });
        if (!company) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        if (telNr) {
            company.telNr = telNr;
        }
        if (fax) {
            company.fax = fax;
        }
        if (mail) {
            company.mail = mail;
        }
        if (website) {
            company.website = website;
        }
        if (notes) {
            company.notes = notes;
        }
        if (companyName) {
            company.companyName = companyName;
        }

        try {
            await this.save(company);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new InternalServerErrorException();
        }
    }
```

basically i have alot of optional parameters and writing an if statement around it just to check if its there feels really wrong. is there a much cleaner way of writing all this togehter? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that holds your properties from `editCompanyDto` which you want to check for set

```
const propertiesToChecked = ["companyName", "telNr", "fax", "mail", "website", "notes"];
```

Get `customer` object keys, filter those keys that exist in `propertiesToChecked` array and their value set in `editCompanyDto` object, these are the properties that we need to replace in `customer`.

```
Object.keys(customer).filter(key => propertiesToChecked.includes(key) && editCompanyDto[key])
.map(key => (customer[key] = editCompanyDto[key]));
```

This is not any design pattern. Just the way to avoid multiple if checks.

So finally your code will look like this :

```
async editCompany(editCompanyDto: EditCompanyDto, id: number) {
    /*const { companyName, telNr, fax, mail, website, notes } =
        editCompanyDto;*/

    const company = await this.findOne({ id });
    if (!company) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    /*if (telNr) {
        company.telNr = telNr;
    }
    if (fax) {
        company.fax = fax;
    }
    if (mail) {
        company.mail = mail;
    }
    if (website) {
        company.website = website;
    }
    if (notes) {
        company.notes = notes;
    }
    if (companyName) {
        company.companyName = companyName;
    }*/

    // Properties to be checked if set
    const propertiesToChecked = ["companyName", "telNr", "fax", "mail", "website", "notes"];

    Object.keys(customer).filter(key => propertiesToChecked.includes(key) && editCompanyDto[key])
    .map(key => (customer[key] = editCompanyDto[key]));

    try {
        await this.save(company);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
}
```

[Similar Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/navnathjadhav/zykrabvd/122/)

Comment: i migh missunderstand the code but the goal of mine is to 1. find the company with the id. 2. check if it there is a company and 3. replace the values of the found company with the values from the dto if they exist. Your code searches for a company with all the values from the dto right?

Comment: This `otherPropNotInArr` (i intensionally added in `editCompanyDto `) is not in `propertiesToChecked ` so it will not be replace in `company`

Comment: but im not trying to create a new company and search with that, im trying to edit the value of the found company with the values fromt the dto

Comment: @Exo Check updated answer. It's what your code will look like.